# How do I add a primary key to a column that may contain null or empty values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Background info:

1. Table *A* has 100 rows in it representing inventory on a shelf. I want to make column *boxCode* a primary key but I can't because the empty rows all have *boxCode* of empty string.
2. Table *B* has a variable amount of rows based on the actual inventory. I want to make column *boxCode* a foreign key linked to Table *A*.

Problem:

Currently I perform 2 SQL queries to make the above operations occur but the action isn't atomic. I update table *A* followed by updating table *B* but there is a small period of time where the tables information is out of sync with each other. This is causing issues with our API. Is there a way in SQL to add or delete rows from Table *B* when I UPDATE Table *A*? I can guarantee I only ever UPDATE Table *A* if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thats 2 questions, please only ask one question per question. And the answer to the first is you can't, a Primary Key must be unique - no exceptions. You normally make your PK a non information column i.e. `id int identity` which contains not actual information, and therefore doesn't matter that every row has a value. Of course you could make your 2 queries atomic by using a transaction. On a *proper* FK you can use cascade delete to automatically delete child records, but there is such thing as automatically add. In fact that suggests a flaw in the design.

Comment: Note that you *can* make a unique index on a column where the column can contain duplicates, known as a "filtered unique index"; in this case you would filter out the rows where the value of `boxcode` is equal to `''`. Such indexes can't be primary key candidates though.

Comment: @DaleK I would agree the design is not ideal or even that great. It sounds like a transaction might be appropriate in my particular case.

Comment: Or a trigger to handle your automatic insert/delete - which is then included in the insert transaction.

Comment: I don't get it: if multiple rows have the same value, how can it be a key? I think you're misunderstanding something here: a primary key is supposed to identify a row, if there are multiple such rows it can't uniquely identify it. What do you expect to happen in such a case?